# Using an UNNESTed field in an UPDATE statement

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with some data. I need to update some rows that match a value in an array. I *don't* need to update the array.

The table looks like:

```
+-------------------------+----------------------+
| timestamp               | arr                  |
+-------------------------+----------------------+
| 2020-03-16 23:00:00 UTC | not_selected         |
|                         | selected_array_value |
| 2020-03-16 22:00:00 UTC | selected_array_value |
| 2020-03-16 21:00:00 UTC | not_selected         |
| 2020-03-16 20:00:00 UTC | selected_array_value |
|                         | not_selected         |
| 2020-03-16 19:00:00 UTC |                      |
+-------------------------+----------------------+
```

I need to change the timestamp for some rows where an *array* contains a *value* like so:

```
+-------------------------+----------------------+
| timestamp               | arr                  |
+-------------------------+----------------------+
| 2020-03-16 12:00:00 UTC | not_selected         |
|                         | selected_array_value |
| 2020-03-16 11:00:00 UTC | selected_array_value |
| 2020-03-16 21:00:00 UTC | not_selected         |
| 2020-03-16 09:00:00 UTC | selected_array_value |
|                         | not_selected         |
| 2020-03-16 19:00:00 UTC |                      |
+-------------------------+----------------------+
```

I can select the items with

```
SELECT * FROM dataset_id.table_id, UNNEST(arr) as array_value
WHERE array_value = 'selected_array_value'
```

What I need to to is something like

```
UPDATE dataset_id.table_id, UNNEST(arr) as array_value
SET timestamp = TIMESTAMP_SUB(timestamp, INTERVAL 11 HOUR)
WHERE array_value = 'selected_array_value'
```

When I attempt this the query doesn't validate as UPDATE doesn't like the comma. I've tried many of variations and can't seem to hit on the syntax. Nor can I find examples of people doing similar things. Any thoughts?

Comment: show example of your data and expected result

Comment: Does that help @MikhailBerlyant ?

Comment: sure. clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE dataset_id.table_id
SET timestamp = TIMESTAMP_SUB(timestamp, INTERVAL 11 HOUR)
WHERE 'selected_array_value' IN UNNEST(arr)
```